# C3PO: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

**Current setup:**

Service host (Java) connects to (JDBC) Primary DB (MySQL RW) and has a worker (read-only) for reliability. Connection management is handled by C3PO

**Scenario:**

In case of flip, I need to promote one of worker to primary DB. Present primary becomes read-only and new primary is promoted to read-write. I am looking to **reliably**, automatically refresh the C3P0 connection pool to the new primary db. Which kind of works now but is broken for certain cases.

**Technical**: Service has a db host as cname, which would be updated on flip. Before the DNS changes propagate and new db is RW, all connections would fail. Trying to set the C3PO retry infinetly on the connection pool until a connection is RW through (acquireRetryAttempts)

**Existing C3PO configuration:**

```
Generic configuration, inherited by primary and worker DB
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="44000"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2"/>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="15000"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000"/>

Primary DB specific config
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
    <property name="connectionTesterClassName" value="${Custom.connectionTesterClassName}"/>
```

**Issue:**

Custom connection tester checks if the connection is writable (@@global.read_only) and return connection invalid or valid. The C3PO runs into issue where it would refurbish (kill and reinitialize) the connection pool as stated in intermediate logs. Eventually it checks out all (max_pool_size, 5) connections (in 4-5 min) and hangs in a state where connections don't checkin back to the pool. This causes all subsequent DB connection checkout to timeout and fail as stated in final logs. Forcing to restart services so it would reinitialize C3PO pool.

Ideally I need the connection pool to keep killing and reinitializing if the `connectionTesterClassName` returns false or on `idleConnectionTestPeriod` or at some random period. Since the connections are checked out they do not fall under idle connections and aren't refreshed.

Tried to debug using `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` as stated in [C3PO documentation](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients) however, no luck.

**Logs:**

Intermediate logs

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: Resource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@24e7ebec] could not be refurbished in preparation for checkout. Will try to find a better resource.
    (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2tyqoiac1gfqk68krloa8|7e2c64]-HelperThread-#6) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: Preparing to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@24e7ebec
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,780 [DEBUG]com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: acquire test -- pool size: 0; target_pool_size: 3; desired target? 1
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,780 [DEBUG]  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: awaitAvailable(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4b52cf0c
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,780 [DEBUG]  (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2tyqoiac1gfqk68krloa8|7e2c64]-HelperThread-#6) com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Preparing to destroy PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@24e7ebec
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,780 [DEBUG]  (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2tyqoiac1gfqk68krloa8|7e2c64]-HelperThread-#6) com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Successfully destroyed PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@24e7ebec
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,780 [DEBUG]  (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2tyqoiac1gfqk68krloa8|7e2c64]-HelperThread-#6) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@24e7ebec
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,781 [DEBUG]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7fff041e] on CHECKOUT.
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,782 [INFO]  ReadWriteConnectionTester: Connection com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@21eb35f6 [wrapping: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@44732406] is read only!
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,782 [DEBUG]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@21eb35f6 [wrapping: null]: close() called more than once.
23 Sep 2020 22:06:23,782 [DEBUG]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7fff041e] on CHECKOUT has FAILED.
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is invalid
```

Final logs:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: Obtaining JDBC connection
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: acquire test -- pool is already maxed out. [managed: 5; max: 5]
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: awaitAvailable(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4b52cf0c

com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils: Converting Throwable to SQLException...
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@43aeb5e0 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]

org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Could not open connection [n/a]
java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar:0.2.10]
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar:0.2.10]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]

Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@43aeb5e0 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    ... 51 more

org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this isn't the right interpretation "refurbish (kill and reinitialize) the connection pool".

It's an individual `Connection` that the pool is trying to "refurbish" here. It's trying to freshen the `Connection` up to be ready for use by the client. Since you have `testConnectionOnCheckout` set to true, and the DB has "flipped", your ReadWriteConnectionTester will declare every Connection in the current pool invalid (because read-only) until the pool runs out of Connections to try or runs out of time due to client timeout.

Does your ReadWriteConnectionTester return `ConnectionTester.CONNECTION_IS_INVALID` or `ConnectionTester.DATABASE_IS_INVALID` when it finds a `Connection` is invalid? You should want it to return `ConnectionTester.DATABASE_IS_INVALID` to get it to reset the whole pool.

Comment: Just to be clear, on detecting RO mode I should return `ConnectionTester.DATABASE_IS_INVALID` which would keep kill and refresh entire connection pool. Keep retrying the same infinetly (acquireRetryAttempts =0) with larger retry delay (may be acquireRetryDelay = 30000) 

Is there any better way to achieve the same ?

Comment: If you return `ConnectionTester.DATABASE_IS_INVALID` it resets the pool. It will kill all outstanding Connections, and try to replace `minPoolSize`. When it tries to replace connections, if the DBMS is not ready, then maybe a round of acquisition attempts fails. That's cool, it will try again on next client request, until eventually it succeeds and can reassemble itself.

Comment: I see, makes sense. However, if an individual connection is returned `CONNECTION_IS_INVALID` by ReadWriteConnectionTester, does it kill and reinitialize a connection (to maintain min pool size) ? I have seen instances where the connections appear (mysql: show process_list;) on new primary db (RW). 


However, sometimes as time progress I saw timeout as shown above.

Comment: got it, will try the same. Thanks for your inputs Steve. I see a performance trade off between the two. Highly appreciate your help

Comment: The connection pool still fails on the same error Steve. 

I monitored the process on mysql database and I saw for few minutes the `writer user` threads keep killing and respawning (since db is set to RO mode) and they give up in some time. I see no new threads killed and reconnected (show processlist) and they hang on for long time until they are churned by `maxIdleTime` property.

Can something be done from C3PO to auto refresh infinetly assuming it succeeds at some point.

Comment: unless you set ['breakAfterAcquireFailure'](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#breakAfterAcquireFailure) to true, c3p0 will continue to retry whenever it receives client requests, even after a round of acquisition attempts fails. it sounds like your issue may be a bit different, that c3p0 succeeds for a while at refreshing the pool, but with Connections that are still read-only. i'm not sure how things work for you at the DBMS end, determining whether readable or writable Connections get dispatched to a fixed JDBC URL.

Comment: But nothing stops you from tapping the pool until whatever has to happen happens, and you start getting writable Connections. There will be some churn and some delay in all the attempts until a success though.

Comment: `breakAfterFailure` is not set, hence I assume by default is set to false from docs Steve. I see C3PO refreshing pool (mysql process list shows the process for writer user is reinitialized for some time) Eventually pools bursts out (connections are visible from mysql in sleep, not being able to checkout since there are no active connections available) and the connections on process list sleep there for long time until they are cleaned by `maxIdleTime`. Pool would be refreshed if db is in RO mode for 2-3 or ~5 min minutes and then I see the stale connections which can't even be checked out.

Comment: >  I'm not sure how things work for you at the DBMS end, determining whether readable or writable Connections get dispatched to a fixed JDBC URL ?

Write connections have a different JDBC URL (primary/master db) and a separate connection pool, so is read connections.